# Windows phone 8, How to use a slider checkbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There is a new style of checkbox used in windows phone 8 (metro?!) similar to slider.

I can manipulate a slider, but I want to know is there a specific control available for use or I should make it myself?

```
<Slider Maximum="1" Minimum="0" Width="70"/>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the `ToggleSwitch` (first setting in [this image](http://blogs.windows.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-53-71-metablogapi/wp_5F00_ss_5F00_20130213_5F00_0006_5F00_5A282D39.png)). The control is available in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

i hope you wish this kind of sliding check box.

please refer this link

**[Slider Check box like default windows phone setting](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-toggleswitch-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api)**

I hope you will get the solution.